# How can I change the color of the selected item in a menu?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/index.php/about/

I want that when the user clicks on the menu item selected to have red.
I tried the code below but do not understand why do not work.

I found more information about this but I do not understand why the work is something wrong in writing code?

```
.navbar .nav > li > a:active{color:red;}
```

I am convinced that it is something very simple but fail to figure out what the problem.

You can help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to toggle class using jquery to change the class when the button is clicked.

Comment: @stanze: sorry, it won't work. After link is clicked, page is reloaded and javascript (nor jquery) don't know what was clicked before reloading. The second thing is that this is CSS task, not JS (nor any JS framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
li.current_page_item > a {
    color: #F00 !important;
}
```

Comment: work, please can you tell me where you got class '.current_page_item?'

Comment: I checked it with chrome inspector

Comment: yes but where you find it ... you can do a print screen please?

Answer (score 1):

`:active` pseudoclass is just a moment when you click and has mouse button down.

Active item in your case has class `current_page_item`, so:

```
.current_page_item > a {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest (but limited since it's coloring all the visited links) is using the :visited selector, like the old days when visited links turned purple.
Other option would be to add a css class .active which applies the desired color. This could be done in plain HTML (then you have to configure this for every single page) or in PHP (by comparing current page with the URL; if it is the same, apply .active)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your style sheet and try.

```
a:hover, a:active {
  outline: 0;
  color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggested to add a class when navigation clicks.
For example :

```
<a href="http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/">Highlights</a>
```

Add class to it when click

```
<a class="active" href="http://paul.dac-proiect.ro/">Highlights</a>
```

CSS

```
.active{
       color : #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
li.current_page_item > a {
    color: red !important;
}
```

because you used

```
li.current_page_item > a {
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```

so you need to change `color` from `#000000` to `red`.